# How do I redirect a POST form submit as if it was originally submitted to another page?

Tags: c#, asp.net, forms, http

Here's my scenario:

I have one page that collects certain data from the user. 
I want to have one button that the user can click, and I want this button to do two things.

a) Log data to my database.
b) Redirect the user to Paypal to make a payment.

My current thought is to create an intermediate "handler" page which will do a) and then redirect the brower to b).

The question is: How do I actually do b)? (Is it some combination of JS and ASP?)
My hope is to have it behave exactly as if the data-collecting page had performed the POST to PayPal directly, but if that is not possible, I welcome other suggestions to implement my scenario.

The back end technology I am using is ASP.NET.

Comment: after you save data, you can redirect user using response.redirect with some values that will help you to identify after successful paypal payment and postback to you, check samples here https://cms.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/library_download_sdks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After some more specific Googling and testing, the solution that worked out for me was to use the code linked here:

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/ASP_NETRedirectAndPost.aspx

> As you can see ... we prepare the POST form which is an HTML form that holds the hidden fields of your POSTed data and a script tag which holds the submit operation of the form .. which will be executed immediately upon the postback.

```
private static String PreparePOSTForm(string url, NameValueCollection data)
{
    //Set a name for the form
    string formID = "PostForm";
    //Build the form using the specified data to be posted.
    StringBuilder f = new StringBuilder();
    f.Append("<form id=\"" + formID + "\" name=\"" + 
                   formID + "\" action=\"" + url + 
                   "\" method=\"POST\">");

    foreach (string key in data)
    {
        f.Append("<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"" + key + 
                       "\" value=\"" + data[key] + "\">");
    }

    f.Append("</form>");
    //Build the JavaScript which will do the Posting operation.
    StringBuilder s = new StringBuilder();
    s.Append("<script language="'javascript'">");
    s.Append("var v" + formID + " = document." + 
                     formID + ";");
    s.Append("v" + formID + ".submit();");
    s.Append("</script>");
    //Return the form and the script concatenated.
    //(The order is important, Form then JavaScript)
    return f.ToString() + s.ToString();
}
```

Comment: Compile the above form, Then `Response.Clear();
            Response.Write(html);
            Response.End();`

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way would be to do this code behind.

Just do your logic in the event handler of the button click.

Then redirect to paypal using

```
Response.Redirect
```

I assume you are just creating a custom URL to go to PayPal.

If you do want to do a POST to another page then you can do this via code behind as well

```
WebClient client = new WebClient();

client.Headers["Content-type"] = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";

response = client.UploadString("http://www.paypal.com/somethingorother", 
                               "parameter1=value1&parameter2=value2");
```

Comment: How will Response.Redirect know what data to POST, if there was never a POST to begin with?

Comment: I'm using a standard PayPal URL with custom POSTed parameters.

Comment: When you click a button there is a POST to your server with your code. This is what will contain all the values in the fields that you filled out. So Paramter1 is the name of one of the input fields in the form, whatever it is called replace Parameter1 with that, then replace value1 with the value of that field, such as txtTextbox1.Text. If you have just copied and pasted from Paypal you will need to add the runat="server" and have an Id for each field, or create your own form from scratch.